# Container overflows outside HTML

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to figure out where the extra spacing on the right of my container comes from, i can't seem to find a element that goes outside the HTML tags using inspector.

[Live Preview](https://chidev.nl)

Any help is appriciated,

Thanks in advance!

Comment: .slider-description[_ngcontent-c3], .slider-title[_ngcontent-c3] remove the left: 10%;

Comment: The only thing you need to do here is to declare an `overflow` property for the containing element of the slider, e.g: `#slider {
    overflow: hidden;
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is coming from this class

```
slider-title tk-futura-pt-bold
```

instead of using position and left on the above class.

Use the follwing to re-position your div (slider):

```
left: 10%;
top: 10%;
transform: translate(10%,10%);
```

Comment: If my answer helped you, could you please accept it?

Comment: Thanks, that was the issue! So much answers in 5 min :D

Comment: @MishaKaras, this is the magic of Stack Overflow. Happy Coding! :)

Answer (score 0):

I would set the `slider-box` to `position: relative;` and set the `slider-title` to `position: absolute;` this would solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

write this code at the end of your css and you will get the problem solved :)

```
.slider-description[_ngcontent-c3], .slider-title[_ngcontent-c3] {
  width: calc(100% - 10%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of **left: 10%;** use **padding-left: 10%;** in  **.slider-title tk-futura-pt-bold** class

Answer (score -1):

The elements with classes slider-description and slider-title have css styling left added to it.

You can fix this by using the following:

```
#slider{
    .slider-box {
        position: absolute;
        left: 10%;
        top: 170px;
    }

    .slider-description, .slider-title{
        color: #fff;
    }

    .slider-title {
        font-size: 24px;
    }

    .slider-description{
        width: 500px;
    }
}
```